# How to get the domain name of my React frontend which is making a request to my Django backend?

Tags: reactjs, django

I want Django to print the domain name of the React frontend which is making a request to my Django server. `get_current_site` gives the domain name of the Django server. So how can I get the domain name of the site, making a request to the Django server?

Comment: You can use the value of the `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` but note that the browsers can be configured not to send this header.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks that did it. Chrome sent this header but do you know which browsers won't?

Comment: The user can configure any browser, or install an extension, to hide or change the referrer header (or any other client request headers). The rule of thumb is to never trust the client.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks again. Will definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: If you are concerned that unauthorized clients can send requests to your Django based API; session based API keys or CSRF is the way to go.

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, I have already taken care of that using JWT Authentication. I was just curious if I can do that.